# How to compile C++ into portable LLVM code

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I have faced a problem compiling LLVM code on a different architecture. And the main issue I can't solve so far is a different pointer size.

clang have always optimize `sizeof(void*)` to an actual pointer size on target machine.

Is it really possible to compile C++ to a portable LLVM code or it is only a marketing trick.

Comment: I don't get your question. What do you expect `sizeof(void*)` to return? It _does_ the return the pointer size on the architecture the program is compiled for, on _all_ compilers. And what do you mean with _portable LLVM code_?

Comment: Two technologies that allow you to compile C++ to a portable executable format are [PNaCl](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client) and [emscripten](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/). Both rely on LLVM. However, LLVM itself markets no such feature.

Answer (score 5):

LLVM bitcode isn't meant to be portable across architectures. It can be in theory but mostly isn't. IIRC this misunderstanding is why LLVM no longer stands for 'Low Level Virtual Machine'.

Google's [Native Client](http://nativeclient.googlecode.com/svn/data/site/pnacl.pdf) achieves portability by having the same target ABI for all platforms and then translating that ABI to the underlying platform ABI.

Answer (score 1):

This is a FAQ: http://llvm.org/docs/FAQ.html#can-i-compile-c-or-c-code-to-platform-independent-llvm-bitcode . Beyond that, Magnus Hoff's pointers to PNaCl and emscripten are on point.